# xcode 4 dot notation code sense problem

Tags: xcode, sense

if i use dot notation in xcode 4 code completion doesn't work for me (pressing ESC):

```
NSString *s = @"demo";
NSLog(@"%lu", [s length]); //[s <ESC> code completion works fine
NSLog(@"%lu", s.length); //s.<ESC> code completion doesn't work
```

??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the property has a valid @property accessor defined.

// in .h

@property (assign) int length;

// in .m

@synthesize length;

Keep in mind you can have your own accessors and setters, but I think code-sense needs @property to show up the dot notation.

Comment: This is correct. Xcode's Code Sense won't autocomplete dot-notation for things that aren't actually properties. It will work at runtime, but you are discouraged from using dot-notation for things that aren't properties.

Comment: But isn't 'length' a property of NSString (Reference says it is a method but s.length() doesn't work) ?

Comment: Ok s.length should be avoided since length is a method, and dot notation should be used only for properties ?

Comment: Gert, depends on how you use / declare it.  You can certainly use it and declare it as a property.  In both cases, length is a method.  In the event that "length" calculates something, then I would use a simple method call to be consistent.  But if length returns an internal variable, then declaring it as a @property and using dot-notation makes things simpler and easier to understand.  Also, don't forget to upvote / mark the answer.  Thanks!